# Copy / export channel entry content

Tags: channel-entries, export, migration, content, backup

I have a production and local environment that I want to be able to transfer content between. I can't take a copy of the database as the production environment and local will be at different stages of the project.

My ideal would be to export channel entry content (including grid and matrix) and then import that into the production site.

Does anyone know of a module, script etc... that does this?

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 0):

Syncing entries can fraught with danger and you need to stick to one direction ie. dev>live or vice versa.

I'd look at grabbing a copy of [DataGrab](http://brandnewbox.co.uk/products/details/datagrab) and installing that on the live server.

On the dev server, you will have to create templates that renders each channels entries as XML or json objects. There can be some tweaking required dependant on your actual content/fieldtype but there's plenty of info around and the docs for DataGrab are a good start.

Visit/save the output of the XML/json templates on your dev server.

On the live server, place a copy of the dev servers object. Jump into DataGrab and configure where the file is & how you want the data to be treated. There's plenty of options and you may need to tweak your source format especially for grid fields or complicated fields.

Remember to test, test, test.